# .PLY animation to alembic/cache

Tags: mesh, cache, alembic

I know similar questions have been asked elsewhere here but, the most recent answer is over 3 years old and we've have b2.8 drop in the interim.

I have captured some depth footage using an Intel Realsense camera. I wound up dumping it to .PLY files (1 per frame with about 4800 frames) and would like to load it (I think) into an alembic file so that I can have a single asset that I can also theoretically apply modifiers to for post processing.

What is the current favored workflow for processing a large stack of sequential .PLY files into an alembic cache in b2.8?

Thanks!